# ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I follow the sample in

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/

it run successfully, then I try to change it to connect to my local sql server, so I add

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

in pom.xml, and in application.properties, I change it to

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update 
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;databaseName=db_example
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=p@ssw0rd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

and then in my run configuration, I kept it unchange, that is,

java 17, -cp accessing-data-mysql-complete

com.example.accessingdatamysql.AccessingDataMysqlApplication
[image: run configuration]

then I run this configuration, but now error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)    at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)     at
> org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:283)  at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.driverClassIsLoadable(DataSourceProperties.java:190)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.determineDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:171)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.initializeDataSourceBuilder(DataSourceProperties.java:123)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) .......

is shown, why? the same run configuration is success to run the mysql sample.

2. and in intellij console, I cannot see what classpath it is using, any method to show the classpath this run configuration is using?
3. in intellij project settings > Modules > Dependencies, I just see
   Maven: com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.0.31
   but no
   mssql-jdbc
   although my pom.xml has it, why?
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver at

The SQL server JDBC library is still hasn't added to your classpath for some reason.

Make sure that after adding the `mssql-jdbc` in `pom.xml`, you click the  button in IDEA's top right to load the `pom.xml`. See here for details:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#maven_reimport

Also, I noticed that you have two modules. Check if you have added the SQL server JDBC library in the correct module.

After succeeding in adding it, the IDEA should be able to show it in `Settings > Modules > Dependencies`.

> and in intellij console, I cannot see what classpath it is using, any method to show the classpath this run configuration is using?

When running, the IDEA will show the full command for running this program in the Run tool window's first line[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGudI.png).
You could copy it, and check the classpath there.

Comment: when I reload the project, it show error "Cannot reconnect." in Sync tab, what is it?

Comment: @user1169587 Might be related to this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247792/Maven-Download-sources-cannot-reconnect
Try to open the Maven tool window in the IDEA's right sidebar, click the reload button 1-2 times to see if it helps, or try to restart the IDEA and reload it again.